# Regex expression failing in bash

Tags: bash

Why does this regex not work in bash?

```
 if [[ "$vl" =~ ^ *[{-].* ]]; then
```

I want to match any number of spaces followed by `{` or `-`, with anything after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to escape the space when used inside the test construct like that.

```
if [[ "$vl" =~ ^\ *[{-].* ]]; then
```

However it's often considered better practice to store the regex in a variable

```
pattern='^ *[{-].*'
if [[ "$vl" =~ $pattern ]]; then
```

Also note this will match zero to unlimited spaces since `*` is used, if you want to ensure there is at least one space you should use `+`

Also the `.*` at the end is not needed since regex doesn't need to match the entire line.

```
pattern='^ +[{-]'
```